# Iterating std::set creates temporaries?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I had to build a `const_iterator` wrapper to exchange generic programming with dynamic binding (never mind this). However `std::set<Base*>::const_iterator::operator*()` gives me something I didn't expect, because I have trouble returning it in a `Derived* const&` where `Derived` publicly inherits from `Base`.

```
template <typename T, typename Container> class StdConstIterator : public ConstIteratable<T> {
  private:
    typename Container::const_iterator it;
  public:
    T const& operator*() const {
      return *it; // g++ says: warning: returning reference to temporary
    }
};

// invokation
StdConstIterator<Derived*,std::set<Base*> > si;
```

While I see that it might be reasonable for pointers to copy them instead of returning a reference, I fail to find a specialisation in my STL's implementation. Could you shed some light on the issue, please?

*Note: You might know the routine; Unfortunately no C++11 support, so I cannot `decltype` myself out of this. But this is more of a "what the heck is going on here?" sort of question, anyway.*

Comment: @fefe: Nope, but I can see how you can easily misread `typename` for `typedef` :)

Comment: @fefe: No, `it` is a variable.

Comment: ¤ `it` is of type `Container::const_iterator`, and so presumably `*it` is of type `Container const`. You're binding that to a `T const&`. If `T` is `Container` or an accessible base class then it's just passing a reference and technically OK, but if `T` is something else then at best you're constructing a temporary for the binding. And in your invocation example `T` is something else. You don't show the definitions so not much more can be said. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I would guess the main problem here is the implicit downcast that you seem to be expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely is that there's some conversion going on. Instead of `T` you should use the actual iterator's value type, `typename Container::const_iterator::value_type`. If that type isn't the same as `T`, then the conversion creates a temporary, to which you attempt to return a reference.

On the other hand, if you do want the conversion, then return by value, `T operator*() const`.

Comment: Ah! Of course, didn't think of non-trivial conversions that actually change the address. Thanks.

Comment: @bitmask: To be really pedantic, you should probably use iterator traits, i.e. `std::iterator_traits<Container::const_iterator>::value_type` ;-)

Comment: I can't, because I have to make the pure virtual requirements of the interface I'm implementing happy. So, I'm returning `ConstRefUnlessPtr<T>::Type` which expands to `T const&` for non-pointer types and to `T` for pointer types. Go ahead, call it a hack :)

Comment: @bitmask: Hm, unrelatedly, have you checked out Boost's transform iterators?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but doesn't help that much in this case, I think.